# MATLAB - how to create condition with specific requirements

Tags: matlab, simulation, statements

I'm simulating water heating and I need to create certain condition and I dont know how to create it properly.

Required temperature of water is 55 °C. Minimal temperature is 50 °C. Maximum temperature is 70 °C.

I have 2 types of heating - electrical heating which heats water to required temperature 55 °C and photovoltaic heating which can heat water to maximum temperature.

I need to create condition which turn on electrical heating only if temperature drops below 50 °C and stops after reaching 55 °C. If the temperature is between 50 and 55 without previously dropping under 50 °C only photovoltaic heating is possible and electrical heating is off.

Temperature is checked every minute for whole year. Conditions will be placed in for cycle.

Right now, I have it without condition for required temperature (55 °C) like this:

```
for i = 1:525600
    if (temeprature(i) < 70)
           heating = 1; %heating from photovoltaic
       else
           heating = 0; % heating off
       end
         if (temperature(i) < 50)
          heating = 2; % electric heating when there is not enough power from PV                   
         end
   if heating==0
     calculations
     calling functions
     etc.
     ...
    end
   if heating==1
     calculations
     calling functions
     etc.
     ...
    end 
   if heating==2
     calculations
     calling functions
     etc.
     ...
    end 
 computing temperature with results from conditions
 end
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You will need a switch statement, case(temp<50) turn on electrical heating, in a while loop add +1 to the heating until 50, then break and go into the while statement of photovoltaic heating, add +1 until 55. if(temp>50 && temp<55) turn on photovoltaic heating until 55. That's all.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand how you mean it, but I dont think this will do the thing. I dont want it to jump into photovoltaic heating...once it drops under 50, electrical heating will be on until 55. Temperature can rise just by 0.1 or 0.5 °C (depends on power of heater). Plus I need for cycle to keep counting minutes. If it jumps into while it will not count "i" until getting out of while cycle (or am I wrong?). Maybe simplification (for now) will be better. Let's say that just electrical heating is possible. That means "heater==2" and "heater==0" conditions.

Comment: Temperature between 50 a 55, no heat. If it drops under 50, heat until 55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a function with persistent variable for electric heating:

```
function [el, pv] = whatHeating(T)
persistent elHeat
if (isempty(elHeat))
    elHeat = false; % Initialize to false. The only thing where it matters is if you start at 50<T<55.
end

if (T < 50)
    elHeat = true;
elseif (T > 55)
    elHeat = false;
end
el = elHeat; % You can't return persistent variable directly.

if (T > 70)
    pv = false;
else
    pv = true;
end
```

Then you simply call this function in your main one.

Comment: If I use (call) your function instead of if conditions as in my first post like this: `[el, pv] = whatHeating(T(i))` and `if el==true
     calculations
     calling functions
     etc.
     ...
    end` and `if el==false 
     calculations
     calling functions
     etc.
     ...
    end` and `if pv==true 
     calculations
     calling functions
     etc.
     ...
    end`  Only photovoltaic heating is on and electric is all the time off. EDIT: I dont know how to add whole blocks of code into comment, so I did it like this.

Comment: @LamaObecna I tried it and it seemed to work fine for me. Not sure what was the problem.
T = [53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 60, 63, 67, 70, 72, 75, 70, 60, 55, 53, 51, 49, 51, 53, 56, 60]; produced 
el = [0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0] and 
pv = [1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1].
test code was 
for i = 1 : length(T)
[el(i), pv(i)] = whatHeating(T(i));
end

Comment: I'd like to ask if you would be so kind and looked at the script. I uplouded it here: https://webshare.cz/file/6QL57g2rv6/simulation-7z

I dont really see why it's not working. I rewrote most of it into english from my native language (czech). There are 3 files, your function, my simulation and data of PV (which are loaded automaticaly). I removed everything what's not important right now. Main "thing" is happening in for cycle (as I posted at first post), same syntax. Other stuff is just for parametres defining and showing results. One graph with temperature during year is plotted.

Comment: You can set up power of PV in parametre powerPV. If you set it up to 0 kW, only electrical heating will be possible. Now its working with my basic conditions, your fucntion just needs to be removed from comment section.
Anyway, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @LamaObecna I checked your stuff and commented out lines with heater and used those pv/el variables. I also saved wasel(i) =el; waspv(i)=pv;
Seems the "should you heat" works OK. But you might have made a mistake in the actual heating calculation (or are simply using insufficient heater for the amount of water you want). For example, the first points have T decreasing well below 50 degrees, even though electric heating is on.

Comment: @LamaObecna I found the bug in your code. It was in PV heating part. 
if (-net(i) <= heaterPOWER) ...
power(i) = (-net(i));
Here, you overwrite 2000 by electric heating when T falls below 50 with nearly 0 from PV heating.
The simplest solution would be to have condition if (pv && ~el) instead of if (pv == true).

Comment: It works! Using "if (pv && ~el)" it's working corectly. I know about "bug" you found, it was't edited for this new condition, but it works for previous version. I'm going to make some other changes and improvements. This was one of them and I just was stuck here. Power of the heater is OK. One last question, what does exactly "persistent" do? I'am not very wise  about it after reading matlab help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It creates a variable which persists across function calls. So when you call the function again, you get the same value of the variable. In this case it was used to keep electric heating at the same value, unless T<50 (turn on) or T>55 (turn off).
Documentation is here: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html)